# Error installing sharp with npm on macOS 13

Tags: npm, sharp

I will install [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) on macos 13.4

I get the following error messages:

```
In file included from ../src/common.cc:13:
/usr/local/include/vips/vips8:35:10: fatal error: 'glib-object.h' file not found
#include <glib-object.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp-darwin-x64/src/common.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/wang/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:209:23)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/wang/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node" "/Users/wang/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/wang/Tmp/strapi-project/node_modules/sharp
```

I have already installed the dependencies through brew

```
brew install vips glib
```

glib path is : /usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.78.1 and PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.78.1/lib/pkgconfig

Any ideas in how I can trace what the problem is?

Comment: Why are you building sharp from source instead of using the pre-built binaries?

Comment: My Node project depends on the 'sharp' package. When I try to install the dependencies using 'npm i', I receive the following error @Quentin

Comment: That explains why you are trying to install sharp but it doesn't answer my question. **Why are you building sharp from source instead of using the pre-built binaries?** Have you read the [installation instructions](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install) that tell you how to pick pre-built binaries for your system?

Comment: I'm trying to create a [strapi](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/installation/cli#creating-a-strapi-project) project, but Strapi depends on sharp, and I'm not sure what I should do to successfully install the dependencies and start the Strapi project. @Quentin

Comment: You keep explaining things that have nothing to do with the questions I'm asking! The one about the installation instructions in my last comment should be a straight-forward Yes or No!